# Huge scale MySQL database for stats storage - what do you recommend?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, scale

A project I am busy on now requires many different kinds of stats, most notably number of visits/views to a product detail page for a specific period of time. This would of course require storing each visit in a table, e.g.

id | visit_date (which will be a UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) | product_id | ip_address (for country-related stats)

This way stats can be generated per product and for a selected time-frame and (using a DB like MaxMind GeoIP) per city/country as well.

Only problem is this table will fill with millions and millions of records very quickly. Any recommendations on how I should approach this the most efficient way?

Comment: "Use MongoDB, it's web scale."

Comment: @Simonatmso.net - I think ta.speot.is was referring to http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Partition by RANGE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html
- take visit_date not as INT / BIGINT. use TIMESTAMP for this occasion as there are mysql functions that work with it and this datatype takes the same place. DATETIME however uses more space as it isn't limited to 1970-01-01 ...
- DELETE old records (2 days old for example) and summarize them in another table.
- maybe you can use the MEMORY storage engine on this table which is faster because it doesn't write to the HD
- maybe you can use memcached as alternative to the MEMORY storage
- don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB.
- tune your my.cnf for example with this: http://tools.percona.com/wizard (notice that this isn't a very trivial thing, you could read books about this)
- Use indexes wisely.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com/) storage engine for MySQL, among other optimizations available (sharding etc, tho it's not necessary with Toku immediately).

Deleting or archiving records to a separate MySQL instance(s) once they become irrelevant (criteria determined by the app developer about the expiry time).

And generally, what Stefan N said in his post if you can't use TokuDB for any reason.